# LINQ to SQL array always returns first item?

Tags: linq, arrays

i am using LINQ to SQL. My Database has 3 columns Ref, Due_amount, Due_Date.
Data may look like this, for example.

> 10    02/08/2009 00:00:00 175.0000
>   10    02/09/2009 00:00:00 175.0000
>   10    02/10/2009 00:00:00 175.0000
>   10    02/11/2009 00:00:00 175.0000
>   10    02/12/2009 00:00:00 175.0000
>   10    02/01/2010 00:00:00 175.0000

My code below, returns 6 elements and works, however the Date is always 02/08/2009? if i say change row 2's amount to 150.0000 it then returns the correct date of 02/09/2009?
Any ideas?

```
private static void PopulateInstalments(string Ref, ResponseMessage responseMsg)
        {
            using (DAO dbContext = new DAO())
            {
                IEnumerable<profile> instalments = (from instalment in dbContext.profile
                                                    where instalment.ref == Ref
                                                    select instalment);

                foreach (profile instalment in instalments)
                {
                    if (responseMsg.Instalments == null)
                        responseMsg.Instalments = new ArrayOfInstalments();
                    Instalment tempInstalment = new Instalment();

                    tempInstalment.DueAmount = instalment.Due_amount;
                    tempInstalment.DueDate = instalment.Due_date == null ? "" : instalment.Due_date.ToString();

                    responseMsg.Instalments.Add(tempInstalment);                    
                }
                            }
        }
```

Thanks
Richard

Comment: What's the generated SQL statement from your LINQ?
And also, not sure if it does matter, normally for LINQ 2 SQL, the type returned would be IQueryable instead of IEnumerable, maybe try changing that one also?

Comment: Hi
Sorry its actual a LINQ to entity. I tried IQueryable but no joy. Adding a breakpoint after select instalment); it does indeed return 6 elements but the dates are the same here

Comment: So you said the data is already incorrect immediately after the select? If this is the case then the code you provided won't help us narrow this down. The issue appears to be with your data or your Entity Model. Is there any more background you can provide us with?

Comment: Are you using the VS's utility to generate the entity model?

Comment: Yes i am using VS's utility to gnerate the entity model.
As i say if the values are different, then the correct dates are returned. the entity is accessing a SQL table. There is no primary key on the table, Ref is indexed, unique non-unique and non-clustered.

Comment: i think i have solved the problem. there was no primary key on the SQl table, adding a identity column primary key seems to have fixed it, now i have updated the entity model. I am still puzzled why it didn't work before?

Answer (score 0):

ensure primary key column is set in source (SQL Server Database in this case)